# как перенаправить вывод команды в консоль и файл и при этом получить статус выполнения команды?

Tags: bash, sh

Выполняю в bash например такую строку:

```
$ SQL=`mysql -h $DATABASE_HOST -P $DATABASE_PORT -u$DATABASE_LOGIN \
  -p$DATABASE_PASSWORD $DATABASE_BASE <$file_sql 2>> $SYSTEM_WORK_LOG_FILE` ;\
  local status=$?
```

Как получить вывод не только в файл, а еще и в консоль и при этом получить статус выполнения команды mysql?

Comment: Чё-нить типа `tee`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Создаем группу: stdout выполняемой целевой команды через pipe передается  `tee`, которая выводит данные на консоль и записывает их а файл.
- Для того чтобы статус целевой команды не терялся(не переопределялся статусом последней выполненной команды) - в групе устанавливаем параметр `set -o pipefail`
- Для `tee` устанавливаем поведение, при котором она сразу возвращает ошибку в случае проблем с выводом - `output-error=exit`

Получаем:

```
(set -o pipefail; /path/to/script.sh | tee --output-error=exit -a /path/to/file.log); status=$?
```

Eсли нужно перенаправлять stderr от целевой команды, то делаем его редирект в stdout - `2>&1`:

```
(set -o pipefail; /path/to/script.sh 2>&1 | tee -output-error=exit -a /path/to/file.log); status=$?
```